# Read C struct member static strings from Android

Tags: java, android, c, string, android-ndk

I would like to learn the best way to read 'C' struct member static strings from Android.

For example, here's a nested 'C' struct with static strings:

```
static const struct A
{
    const char* const a;
    struct B
    {
        const char* const b;
    } b;
} a = {"Hello, A", {"Hello, B"}};
```

What is the best way to read these 2 strings from Android?

I am looking for a simple way to do this so that there is minimal or no processing at runtime. From what I read I need to convert the strings to UTF-16, so I may be better off using some kind of wide-char type (jstring) rather than char[]? Do I actually need to create a method and not directly access the strings as member data?

Thanks

Comment: This not a valid structure definition in C. And not a valid assignment either.

Comment: You can access the strings as a sequence of bytes.  You only need to turn it into a UTF-16 if you want a String or a StringBuilder. I would look at the access functions you have for accessing native memory.  Ideally you wouldn't need to read those String from C to Java at all.  Are you sure it is worth using C?

Comment: If you wanna read C data from Java layer, you need to create JNI interface to make a bridge.

Comment: Seva, the code above compiled and as far as I know is valid 'C'. If there is some change I could make to make it conform to the standard, do tell. I suspect you may be thinking I need a typedef, which I could do if that helps clarify the question.

Comment: Peter, I'm not 100% sure, but I have a bunch of data (mostly strings) that really should only exist in 1 place to avoid mistakes. The only common denominator language I can see is 'C'

Comment: yushulx, Yes, JNI, but how. Do I need functions to do this or can I more directly access the strings by doing something at compile time? I hate to have to write conversions for static data if I can avoid it. I'm looking for the most efficient example I can find.